# Shapes that can be saved to a database

Tags: c#, sql

I have been asked to refactor the below code using SOLID principles and I was just wondering how you would go about it. I am not really sure if I am winning or not.

Could you have a stab at it and let me see what you come up with?

```
public class Box
    {
        private BoxType _boxType;

        public double Width { get; set; }
        public double Height { get; set; }
        public double Radius { get; set; }

        public BoxType BoxType
        {
            get { return _boxType; } 
            set { _boxType = value; }
        }

        public void Add()
        {
            using (var con = new SqlConnection())
            {
                SqlCommand cmd;

                if (_boxType == BoxType.Circle)
                {
                    cmd = new SqlCommand(string.Format("insert into [Table] values({0}, {1})", _boxType, Radius), con);
                }
                else
                {
                    cmd = new SqlCommand(string.Format("insert into [Table] values({0}, {1}, {2})", _boxType, Width, Height), con);
                }

                cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
            }
        }

        public double CalculateArea()
        {
            if (_boxType == BoxType.Rectangle)
            {
                return Width * Height;
            }
            else if (_boxType == BoxType.Square)
            {
                return Width * Height; 
            }
            else if (_boxType == BoxType.Circle)
            {
                return Radius * Math.PI;
            }
            else
            {
                return 0;
            }
        }
    }     

    public enum BoxType
    {
        Unknown,
        Square,
        Rectangle,
        Circle
    }
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

## Auto-implemented properties:

```
public BoxType BoxType
{
    get { return _boxType; } 
    set { _boxType = value; }
}
```

This can be replaced by an *auto-implemented property* and will look like this:

```
public BoxType BoxType { get; set; }
```

The compiler will generate a backing-field and this will result in the code you had, but this is cleaner to develop.

## if/else vs. switch:

When you're in a situation where there are a lot of if/else statements, you should consider using a swicth statement. The code in your `CalculateArea()` method would look like this:

```
public double CalculateArea()
{
    switch(BoxType)
    {
        case BoxType.Rectangle:
            return Width * Height;
        case BoxType.Square:
            return Width * Height; 
        case BoxType.Circle:
            return Radius * Math.PI;
        default: return 0;
    }
}
```

## Simplifying code:

This code:

```
SqlCommand cmd;

if (_boxType == BoxType.Circle)
{
    cmd = new SqlCommand(string.Format("insert into [Table] values({0}, {1})", _boxType, Radius), con);
}
else
{
    cmd = new SqlCommand(string.Format("insert into [Table] values({0}, {1}, {2})", _boxType, Width, Height), con);
}
```

can be rewritten to:

```
var query = BoxType == BoxType.Circle ?
        String.Format("insert into [Table] values({0}, {1})", _boxType, Radius) :
        String.Format("insert into [Table] values({0}, {1}, {2})", _boxType, Width, Height);
var sqlCommand = new SqlCommand(query);
```

## `var` and naming variables:

When possible, try to use `var` instead of explicitly declaring your variables. The compiler will determine the type for you so you don't have to worry about that. Also give your variables meaningful names. `con` and `cmd` are not meaningful, better would be `sqlCommand` and `sqlConnection`.

## More reading:

- [**Auto-Implemented Properties**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb384054.aspx)

Comment: While the suggestions are helpful, this doesn't answer the question at all.  None of them have to do with SOLID, so Sleiman's answer should really be marked as correct.

Answer (score 11):

**Note**: I don't claim to be an expert in `SOLID` principles, I do understand `abstraction` a bit though.

Back to `SOLID`, `CalculateArea` violates the `Open/Closed` principle (The most frustrating concept to me). That is, when you add a shape  you have to go and modify the code by adding an `if-statement`, this can easily solved by using `interfaces`,

```
 interface IShape{
    double CalculateArea();
 } 

 class Rectangle : IShape{
    double CalculateArea(){
       return Width * Height;
    }
 }
```

And so on for different shapes, so there is no need for if-statements. Btw: how come you representing a `circle` in a class called `Box`??

Single responsibility principle is being violated as well, where your class represents a Box Object and persists it to a database, these are two different responsibilities. You should rather have Data Access Layer to deal with a very `HIGH dependency` like a database.

In regards to SQL generation you can `abstract` those as well using interfaces, and that is, given a shape get its sql code.

```
  interface ISQLShapeTemplates{
      DbCommand InsertionCode(IShape shape);
      DbCommand SelectCommand(IShape shape); 
  }
```

I used `DbCommand` and not `SqlCommand` because it's more abstract .

Comment: dang... I didn't see the "new answer" box. You beat me to it. ++

Comment: @RubberDuck it's all fine :)

Comment: If I could mark correct as well, I would. Thanks very much for your help :)

Comment: @Mike That's what I want, to help and not to get my answer marked as correct :)

Answer (score 0):

I would create a `Shape` interface and classes for each type of shape. Each different shape class would then implement an `Add` and a `CalculateArea` method specific to that particular shape.